# Magento2 : Get Product Url for Store

Tags: magento2, product, url, stores

I'm writing a custom indexer and I need to retrieve the product URL for different stores.

```
$product->setStoreId(2)->getProductUrl();
```

still returns the URL with the admin store (backoffice) in it.
Do you have an idea how I can retrieve the store specific product URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$product->setStoreId(2)->getUrlInStore();
```

Comment: the call is also returning the url with backoffice in it.

Comment: strange...that used to work for m1. I thought it would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

`$product->setStoreId(2)->getUrlInStore();`

but if you use it from backoffice, be sure that productUrlModel not the backoffice model - it's the bug from the Magento as I suppose. Set **Magento\Framework\Url**

Comment: useful would be an example

Comment: Make sense this answer does not

Answer (score 0):

There are Magento 2 bugs created concerning this issue:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4247
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19196

I have only made a workaround by replacing admin URL with frontend store URL:

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $config;

    /**
     * Url constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getProductUrl(Product $product): string
    {
        $isSecure   = $product->getStore()->isFrontUrlSecure();
        $productUrl = $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, ['_secure' => $isSecure]);

        /**
         * There is a Magento bug with getting product URL from adminhtml area:
         * https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4247
         * https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19196
         *
         * Making a workaround to return proper frontend product URL based on store
         */
        if ($this->isAdminUrlUseCustom()) {
            $productUrl = str_replace(
                $this->getBaseUrl(0, $isSecure),
                $this->getBaseUrl($product->getStoreId(), $isSecure),
                $productUrl
            );
        }

        return $productUrl;
    }

    /**
     * Is admin URL use custom
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isAdminUrlUseCustom(): bool
    {
        return $this->config->isSetFlag('admin/url/use_custom');
    }

    /**
     * Get base url for store
     *
     * @param int  $storeId
     * @param bool $isSecure
     * @return string
     */
    private function getBaseUrl(int $storeId, bool $isSecure): string
    {
        if ($isSecure || 0 === $storeId) {
            return $this->config->getValue(
                'web/secure/base_url',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES,
                $storeId
            );
        }

        return $this->config->getValue(
            'web/unsecure/base_url',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES,
            $storeId
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get product URL store wise using following code.

```
protected $productRepository;
protected $_storeManager;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}



public function getProductUrlStoreWise(int $productId)
{
    
    $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();

    $product    = $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $websiteId);
    $productUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
    return $productUrl;
}
```